# variable is assigned a value but never used when declaring it in Vue data object and using it in a method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I'm getting an error in the webpack cmd window when I run `npm run dev` on a project.

Here is the code and the error message that I get specifically, the code related to the parent top-level Vue component, which has the navbar in that has details that change depending on if the user is logged in:

The code

```
<script>
// import required components
import EventBus from './components/EventBus'
import router from './router/index.js'
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode'

export default {
  data () {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken
    const decoded = jwtDecode(token)
    return {
      first_name: '',
      surname: '',
      email: '',
      created: ''
    }

    return {
      auth: false
    }

    try {
      this.login()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Not currently signed in')
    }
  },

  methods: {
    logout () {
      this.first_name = ''
      this.surname = ''
      this.email = ''
      this.created = ''
      localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
      this.auth = false
      router.push({
        name: 'login'
      })
    },

    login () {
      this.first_name = this.decoded.f_name
      this.surname = this.decoded.s_name
      this.email = this.decoded.email
      this.created = this.decoded.created
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    EventBus.$on('logged-in', status => {
      this.auth = status
      this.login()
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

And the error message

```
  ✘  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars  'decoded' is assigned a value but never used
  src\App.vue:60:11
      const decoded = null
```

To me, it looks like `decoded` is used in `login()`, any ideas?

Comment: Well you're not using `decoded` - it looks like a local variable in `data`.

Comment: 1) `decoded` is not part of the `data` return value so it won't be available in `this.decoded`. The unused local variable is why you get a warning 2) You have multiple `return` statements in `data`. Nothing after the first will be evaluated. 3) You don't want to try calling `login()` in your `data` function. Move it to `created` or `mounted`

Comment: @Phil Thanks. Sorry for my ignorance, but how do i access decoded whilst also declaring it as a const with the value of the decoded token?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to change in your data method

As your data is a function and what gets exposed is return value. you need to return decoded from data()in order to use decoded in your login method.

```
 data () {
        const token = localStorage.usertoken
        const decoded = jwtDecode(token)
        return {
          first_name: '',
          surname: '',
          email: '',
          created: '',
          decoded: decoded
        }
```